# Android Speech Recognition not working on android webview how to fix it?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

when i am trying to open this link https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html on android web view it will give me Web Speech API is not supported by this browser.Upgrade to Chrome version 25 or later. how to fix it ?i have already set WebChromeClient in web view.speech recognition only work on chrome browser?